# Unable to find org.talend.ci:builder-maven-plugin:7.1.1 on the server

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, nexus, talend

I am setting up CICD based on Talend's specifications using Jenkins and Nexus. I get that plugin can not be found on the server but how do I handle the retry because based on below message resolution will not be attempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. How do I clean cache or force update? I get this error when building pipeline in jenkins

```sh
[INFO] [jenkins-event-spy] Generated /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_pipeline@tmp/withMaven9b3f95a4/maven-spy-20190809-185900-6572328407965718335374.log
[ERROR] Plugin org.talend.ci:builder-maven-plugin:7.1.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.talend.ci:builder-maven-plugin:jar:7.1.1 in http://XXXXXXXXX/repository/maven-central/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.talend.ci:builder-maven-plugin:7.1.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.talend.ci:builder-maven-plugin:jar:7.1.1 in http://XXXXX/repository/maven-central/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:244)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:130)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan (BuilderCommon.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is it looking in maven central? Seems like you missed something..

Did you follow the instructions to [Set up Talend Nexus](https://community.talend.com/t5/Architecture-Best-Practices-and/Install-configure-and-automate-Talend-7-Continuous-Integration/ta-p/126949#toc-hId-932757026)

> 6. Create a third repository, choose maven2 (hosted) and configure it, as shown below. This repository is used by Talend CI Builder and is
>      defined later in the maven_user_settings.xml file.

And [Install and configure Talend CommandLine](https://community.talend.com/t5/Architecture-Best-Practices-and/Install-configure-and-automate-Talend-7-Continuous-Integration/ta-p/126949#toc-hId--1419352913)

> 9. Edit the commandlinePath/configuration/maven_user_settings.xml file and add the connection information to the Nexus repositories. In your
>      case, Nexus is on a remote server where you installed the Talend
>      platform, so replace localhost with the private EC2 IP address.

Comment: Issue is now resolved. It was permissions issue on the folder where studio was installed. After giving it the appropriate permissions, Jenkins was able to find the libraries it needed.

Comment: @sam, if the answer provided helped, consider marking as "answered". If it did not, then consider "answer your own question" with the details and close it out for future reference.